# git folder disappearing on checkout

Tags: git

I was working in visual studio earlier and I had to add some sql scripts into the project.

```
I right clicked -> add -> new folder.
```

I added 2 sql scripts, and 1 text file into my new folder. When I was done I went into cmd and did the following:

```
git add -A
git commit -am "message"
git push origin branch
```

this push showed up in the git repo, and I see the files. But now when I try to `git checkout` I keep getting annoying messages about:

> unlink of file failed, should I try again

and when I say "no" 3 times, it just switches the branch but then in visual studio a pop up appears that has options to save/overwrite/undo the changes

I clicked on ignore, and now the folder I created disappeared along with the files. However they're on git, what exactly is going on? Will people who pull that branch get the folder and files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch the branch, then you are on another branch (obviously).

Thus you are on a branch that doesn't contain your folder/files since you commited it on a different branch.

Go back to your branch ?

Comment: I tried going back to my branch but the folder didn't show up

Comment: Since the changes are on the git repo. Check the name of the branch where the folder is. Let's say the name of the branch is "ahmad". Go to your local repo. Make a `git checkout -b ahmad` (if the branch already exists, ignore this step). Then `git pull origin ahmad`